# How to switch Ansible playbook to another host when calling second playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have two playbooks - my first playbook iterates on the list of ESXi servers getting list of all VMs, and then passes that list to the second playbook, that should iterates on the IPs of the VMs. Instead it is still trying to execute on the last ESXi server. I have to switch host to that VM IP that I'm currently passing to the second playbook. Don't know how to switch... Anybody?

First playbook:

```
- name: get VM list from ESXi
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: get facts
    vmware_vm_facts:
      hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      username: "{{ ansible_ssh_user }}"
      password: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: esx_facts

  - name: Debugging data
    debug:
      msg: "IP of {{ item.key }} is {{ item.value.ip_address }} and is {{ item.value.power_state }}"
    with_dict: "{{ esx_facts.virtual_machines }}"

  - name: Passing data to include file
    include: includeFile.yml ip_address="{{ item.value.ip_address }}"
    with_dict: "{{ esx_facts.virtual_machines }}"
```

My second playbook:

```
- name: <<Check the IP received
  debug:
    msg: "Received IP: {{ ip_address }}"

- name: <<Get custom facts
  vmware_vm_facts:
    hostname: "{{ ip_address }}"
    username: root
    password: passw
    validate_certs: False
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: custom_facts
```

I do receive the correct VM's ip_address but vmware_vm_facts is still trying to run on the ESXi server instead...

Comment: For a start please use proper terms: you have one playbook with one play and include a tasks file. So you claim you delegate task to localhost, but it executes elsewhere? If so, you could cut 80% of the code you posted and get the same result.

Comment: Besides, the `<<Get custom facts` task will run several times, for all targets in the inventory, but that is not where it is executing. You might be confused by misreading the log.

Comment: And, of course, the whole idea of running `vmware_vm_facts` twice this way seems pretty strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't afford to setup dynamic inventory for VMs, your playbook should have two plays: one for collecting VMs' IPs and another for tasks on that VMs, like this (pseudocode):

```
---
- hosts: hypervisors
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - vmware_vm_facts:
        ... params_here ...
      register: vmfacts
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item.key }}"
        ansible_host: "{{ item.value.ip_address }}"
        group: myvms
      with_dict: "{{ vmfacts.virtual_machines }}"

- hosts: myvms
  tasks:
    - apt:
        name: "*"
        state: latest
```

Within the first play we collect facts from each hypervisor and populate `myvms` group of inmemory inventory. Within second play we run `apt` module for every host in `myvms` group.

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin! I also had to add ansible_ssh_user and pass, b/c user was show as "NONE"