# The conditional check dict object' has no attribute ansible error

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ansible, jinja2

I have a playbook which runs without issues in us-east-1 , but having issues in ap-southeast-1 in aws. Here is the part of playbook where it fails

```
- hosts: "tag_deployment_group_{{ env }}_{{ app }}"
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: "wait for instances to be reachable"
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 60
    timeout: 500
- ec2_remote_facts:
    region: ap-southeast-1
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
    filters:
      "tag:Env": "{{ env }}"
  register: instance_facts
- add_host:
    name: "{{ item.tags.Name }}"
    ansible_host: "{{ item.private_ip_address }}"
    group: "{{ env }}_{{app}}"
  with_items: "{{ instance_facts.instances }}"
- name: "copy cron script"
  copy: src=/etc/ansible/files/delete.sh dest=/root/scripts/delete.sh
  when: item.tags.app_type == 'platform'
  with_items: "{{ instance_facts.instances }}"
```

The error I get is as follows

```
"failed": true, 
"msg": "The conditional check 'item.tags.app_type == 'platform'' 
failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional 
(item.tags.app_type == 'platform'): 'dict object' has no attribute 
'app_type'\n\nThe error appears to have been 
ts.yml': line 80, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending 
on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n      
with_items: \"{{ instance_facts.instances }}\"\n    - name: \"copy cron 
script\"\n      ^ here\n"
```

Comment: Not really sure, stck here

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `app_type` tag is missing for an instance.

P.S. But I suspect a design flaw in your playbook – if you expect `delete.sh` script to appear on instances with tag `app_type` == 'platform' , then your plabook is wrong.

Comment: Actually It started working after I changed it to  ```` when: "item.tags.app_type is defined and  'platform' in item.tags.app_type"  ````  from your older posts. But , the intention is of the playbook is to copy script if  ``` app_type == 'platform' ```. Could you please explain.

Comment: Generally you should run `add_host` and tasks for that hosts in different plays. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47647197/2795592

Comment: Thanks for clarification . I will implement that way